# How to return results that combine themselves from an attribute the is equal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a database of musical works and in these works the are information about the owners of that works. The owner can be an editor or a composer. There can be many composers and many editors.

Editors and composers have a publishing relationship that is indicated by their attribute called `link`. So, if an editor has a `link = 5` and the composer too, they are linked. Or the editor is the publisher of that composer.

I use this query to get only the musical works that are from the editor I want.

```
db.works.find({'pro_owners.codigo_ecad': 5546730})
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

And it retrieves me some documents like these:

```
{
  "_id": "6042617f0732f22da210e7a6",
  "codigo_ecad": 16403107,
  "iswc": "T0401990268",
  "titulo": "YA INTENTE COMPREENDER",
  "situacao": "LB",
  "data_inclusao": "2017-06-02T03:00:01.000Z",
  "pro_owners": [
    {
      "codigo_ecad": 8096286,
      "owner": "JOSIEL DEL CID",
      "category": "CA",
      "percent": 0,
      "link": "2",
      "_id": "60426160dca0dd0dc8290d41"
    },
    {
      "codigo_ecad": 381928,
      "owner": "THALES ROBERTO DA SILVA",
      "category": "CA",
      "percent": 0.75,
      "link": "1",
      "_id": "6042615bdca0dd0dc8290d32"
    },
    {
      "codigo_ecad": 5546730,
      "owner": "THALES ROBERTO DA SILVA - EIRELI - ME",
      "category": "E",
      "percent": 0.25,
      "link": "1",
      "_id": "6042615bdca0dd0dc8290d33"
    }
  ],
  "client_name": "Datha Editora"
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way query and receive only the unique linked owners of the editor I am interested in. In the above case, just:

```
{
      "codigo_ecad": 381928,
      "owner": "THALES ROBERTO DA SILVA",
      "category": "CA",
      "percent": 0.75,
      "link": "1",
      "_id": "6042615bdca0dd0dc8290d32"
    }
```

The next step would be a `$lookup` to the `owners` collection to return these results with their full data. But it is a plus.

Comment: What makes THALES ROBERTO DA SILVA the only unique owner in your case?

Comment: Do yoy mean you want to [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the array?

Comment: @EugeneBotyanovsky he is the only unique owner that is published by THALES ROBERTO DA SILVA - EIRELI - ME. It can be "read" by the same number at the "link" attribute. JOSIEL is  composer too, as it's category says that he is a "CA" = "Composer/Author". But I don't want him, because he is not published by the "E" = "Editor" "THALES ROBERTO DA SILVA - EIRELI - ME", as the "link" attribute shows a different number.

Comment: @Joe I understand that ```$filter``` could help, but how do I state a filter that in the query that uses an attribute of an item from the array to be matched with an attribute of the other items in the same array? 


```$filter: {
               input: "$pro_owners",
               as: "item",
               cond: { "$$link": "link number of the pro_owners that have a codigo_ecad == 5546730" }
            }```

Or it would be another step with another query? 

Please, propose a solution so I can better look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with aggreation:

- $match to select only document containing a pro_owner with the matching code
- $addFields with $filter to extract the matching pro_owner into a new field
- $addFields/$project with $filter to limit the pro_owners list to those with the same link value as the new field